# rails - undefined method `upletter' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I want to iterate that cards I create in show

Here is the code in index :

```
<div class="container-page">
  <div class="padding-page">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="start-cards">
      <div class="row">
          <h1 class="text-center">Let's</h1>
            <ul class="list-inline text-center">
          <% @hiraganas.each do |hiragana| %>

          <li>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 col-md-3 container-cards">
              <div class="card-details">
                <span class="card-question img-popover" data-content="<h4 class='text-center letter-uppercase'><%= @hiragana.upletter %></h4><p class='text-center'><%= @hiragana.transcription %></p>"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg"></i></span>

                <div class="prononciation"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></div>
                <div class="audioclick">
                  <p><i class="fa fa-volume-off fa-lg"><%= @hiragana.audioclick %></i></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-hiragana hiragana-<%=@hiragana.upletter.downcase.last%>">
                  <p><%= @hiragana.ideoone %></p>
                </div>

                 <div class="card-katakana">
                 <p><%= @hiragana.ideotwo %></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a problem : better errors tells me [![enter image description here][2]][2] undefined method with 'upletter' which is the method I use to generate letter(s) in popover.

```
<% @hiraganas.each do |hiragana| %>
          <li>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 col-md-3 container-cards">
              <div class="card-details">
                <span class="card-question img-popover" data-content="<h4 class='text-center letter-uppercase'><%= @hiragana.upletter %></h4><p class='text-center'><%= @hiragana.transcription %></p>"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg"></i></span>
                <div class="prononciation"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></div>
                <div class="audioclick">
                  <p><i class="fa fa-volume-off fa-lg"><%= @hiragana.audioclick %></i></p>
                </div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes sorry @sawa my question is just why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonjour!

You need:

```
 <%= hiragana.upletter %>
 <%= hiragana.transcription %>
```

In your loop.

-

When using a loop, you need to use the [locally scoped variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable):

```
<% @hiraganas.each do |hiragana| %>
   <%= hirgana.upletter %>
<% end %>
```

---

Any Ruby error with `undefined method "..." for "NilClass"` basically means you're trying to call methods on a non-declared variable.

In this case, the variable you're trying to use is `@hiragana`, which doesn't exist. It's local equivalent (`hirgana`) does.

Comment: Thank you @RichPeck It is strange because I use to work with {@name.method}. I don't really understand why ?

Comment: `@name.method` was probably defined, in this case, `@hiraganas` is not. If you post the code where you were using `@name.method`, I'll be in a better position to provide more scope